# Error in crontab to execute mysql query that exports an xlsx file in bash script

Tags: mysql, bash, cron, centos7

Good day

I use a bash script to export the contents of a mysql database called QoS through an automatic connection through the conexion.cnf file that contains the credentials of my root user. When I execute my script manually it executes correctly and exports the file in the specified location, with name $fecha.xlsx but when the crontab executes nothing happens.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/andres/BD/Perdida

fecha=$(date +%Y-%m-%d' '%H:%M);

mysql --defaults-file=/etc/my.cnf.d/conexion.cnf -D QoS -e "SELECT * FROM Throughput_TX" > /home/andres/BD/Scripts/$fecha.xlsx
```

Crontab

```
* * * * * /bin/bash -lc /home/andres/BD/Scripts/ Throughputprueba.sh > /dev/null
```

I use the root user.

Very thanks.

Answer (score 0):

your environmental variables may not be set.

you first need to set appropriate environmental variables, then execute your script.

try

```
#!/bin/bash
. /home/andres/.bash_profile #<-- this part need to address your bash_profile.
cd /home/andres/BD/Perdida

fecha=$(date +%Y-%m-%d' '%H:%M);

mysql --defaults-file=/etc/my.cnf.d/conexion.cnf -D QoS -e "SELECT * FROM Throughput_TX" > /home/andres/BD/Scripts/$fecha.xlsx
```

alternatively you give full path of mysql.

```
whereis mysql
```

get the path and add in-front-of   `/<full-path>/mysql --defaults-file=...`

Edit: your cron has syntax error

```
* * * * * /bin/bash -lc /home/andres/BD/Scripts/ Throughputprueba.sh > /dev/null
```

to

```
* * * * * /bin/bash -lc /home/andres/BD/Scripts/Throughputprueba.sh > /dev/null
```

Comment: when entering the code whereis mysql replies with mysql: / usr / bin / mysql / usr / lib / mysql / usr / share / mysql / usr / share / man / man1 / mysql.1.gz so add this to the start of the line where the query is made and it did not work.

#!/bin/bash
. /home/andres/.bash_profile
cd /home/andres/BD/Scripts

fecha=$(date +%Y-%m-%d' '%H:%M);

/</usr/bin/mysql /usr/lib/mysql /usr/share/mysql /usr/share/man/man1/mysql.1.gz>/mysql --defaults-file=/etc/my.cnf.d/conexion.cnf -D QoS -e "SELECT * FROM Perdida" > /home/andres/BD/Scripts/$fecha.xlsx

Comment: `/usr/bin/mysql -defaults-file=/etc/my.cnf.d/conexion.cnf -D QoS -e "SELECT * FROM Throughput_TX" > /home/andres/BD/Scripts/$fecha.xlsx`

Comment: it does not work.

/usr/bin/mysql --defaults-file=/etc/my.cnf.d/conexion.cnf -D QoS -e "SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM Throughput_TX ORDER BY fecha DESC LIMIT 5) sub ORDER BY fecha ASC" > /home/andres/BD/Scripts/$fecha.xlsx

entry to the cront log, but I do not understand much about this.

Comment: The solution is:

*/10 * * * * sh /home/andres/Proyecto/Scripts/Perdida/QoSperdida.sh > /dev/null

Answer (score 0):

And two point:

1. You run your script too often. Check how much time it take to run
   the script and make frequency of run to less than this value
2. You have one space in your script which will result as never execute
   the shell script

   `* * * * * /bin/bash -lc /home/andres/BD/Scripts/ Throughputprueba.sh
                                                   ^`

And you do not need to run one more bash, run cron like this:

```
* * * * * /home/andres/BD/Scripts/Throughputprueba.sh
```

Comment: Hello, I have already corrected what you indicated to me and it does not work.

Comment: @AndresAndrade, did you add `.bash_profile` and/or `.bashrc` in to the script?

Comment: @AndresAndrade, and check in cron log about additional information.

Comment: Crontab 
*/3 * * * * /home/andres/BD/Scripts/Throughputprueba.sh > /dev/null

Code

#!/bin/bash
. /home/andres/.bash_profile
cd /home/andres/BD/Scripts

fecha=$(date +%Y-%m-%d' '%H:%M);

mysql --defaults-file=/etc/my.cnf.d/conexion.cnf -D QoS -e "SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM Throughput_TX ORDER BY fecha DESC LIMIT 5) sub ORDER BY fecha ASC" > /home/andres/BD/Scripts/$fecha.xlsx

Comment: @AndresAndrade, remove redirection to `null`(for now) and check in logs what you see. You can add it later after you have script run properly

Comment: These are the last log of the contrab log.

Jan 14 11:12:01 localhost crond[5597]: (root) RELOAD (/var/spool/cron/root)
Jan 14 11:12:01 localhost CROND[19419]: (root) CMD (bin/bash -lc /home/andres/BD/Scripts/Throughputprueba.sh )
Jan 14 11:15:01 localhost CROND[19466]: (root) CMD (bin/bash -lc /home/andres/BD/Scripts/Throughputprueba.sh )

Comment: @AndresAndrade, so it run. In such case redirect output to some file for inspection. Also you can add to script `-x` to see debug information

Comment: Redirected the output to a txt file and is empty.

Comment: Do it also with STDERR

Comment: I have added set -xv to the script to debug and it responds in the log that the redirect is ambiguous.

*/2 * * * * /home/andres/BD/Scripts/Throughputprueba.sh > /home/andres/BD/Scripts/cron_error.log 2>&1

Comment: The solution is: */10 * * * * sh /home/andres/Proyecto/Scripts/Perdida/QoSperdida.sh > /dev/nul

Comment: @AndresAndrade, seems like you do not add execution permissions to the script. The command is `chmod +x /home/andres/Proyecto/Scripts/Perdida/QoSperdida.sh`